# Adding @angular/fire to angular 12

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, angularfire, angular12

I am trying to add @angular/fire to my Angular 12 project so I can deploy it on Firebase.
I used the cli to add @angular/fire
I run:

```
ng add @angular/fire
```

Here is the output I get:

```
ℹ Using package manager: npm
✔ Found compatible package version: @angular/fire@0.0.0.
✔ Package information loaded.
 
The package @angular/fire@0.0.0 will be installed and executed.
Would you like to proceed? Yes
✔ Package successfully installed.
The package that you are trying to add does not support schematics. You can try using a different version of the package or contact the package author to add ng-add support.
```

I tried using npm to install the dependency:

```
npm i @angular/fire
```

Heres is the Output:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/animations@12.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.14.1 || ^14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.13.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/common@12.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.14.1 || ^14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.13.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/compiler@12.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.14.1 || ^14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.13.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/compiler-cli@12.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.14.1 || ^14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.13.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/core@12.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.14.1 || ^14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.13.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/forms@12.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.14.1 || ^14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.13.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/platform-browser@12.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.14.1 || ^14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.13.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic@12.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.14.1 || ^14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.13.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@angular/router@12.0.0',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^12.14.1 || ^14.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.1.0', npm: '7.13.0' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }

up to date, audited 1388 packages in 6s

3 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ng-jumbo-fire",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/common": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^0.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.0.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1102.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.2.4"
  }
}
```

How do I get it installed. I notice that @angular/fire is at version 0.0.0. The folder .node_modules/@angular/fire is empty.
I'll appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the compatibility matrix, it's not fully supported with Angular 12 yet. So you might be better off with using Angular 11 instead.

[image]
Source: https://github.com/angular/angularfire#compatibility

Comment: Thank You. Appreciate it. I will try to use the firebase tools to launch my firestore. I've deployed it but still working around how to implement firestore into the app. Any help would be a huge push for me.

Answer (score 2):

For Angular 12 below dependencies with such version resoloved my issues.

Install *firebase* version *7.0 || 8.0* and *@angular/fire* version *6.1.5*.

*package.json* folder dependencies should look like:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"@angular/fire": "^6.1.5",
"firebase": "^7.0 || ^8.0"
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';

  imports: [
    ...
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule
  ],
```

Comment: I am unable to get token in request permission method